# Enabling keyboard navigation in the Bootstrap dropdown-menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accessibility, keyboard-navigation

Is it possible to navigate using the keyboard to the drop down menu using <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and navigate using the arrow keys to the sub elements of the drop down?

Here is the code I have now:

```
<input type="text" value="click tab to jump to the drop down."/>
<div class="bs-docs-example">
    <div class="dropdown clearfix">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display: block; position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 180px;">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item A</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item B</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item C</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item A1</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item B1</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">You should navigate here with the keyboard.</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Thanks For your Help!</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MGwVM/1/

Comment: I see you edited after I answered. Did you see my answer?

Comment: Late comment, but... I think nowadays we can just add role="menu" to the ul.dropdown-menu and role="navigation" to the div.navbar (in both bootstrap 2 and 3) and that seems to enable keyboard accessibility pretty well. But I think the html markup in your question doesn't follow the bootstrap examples...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Update

Bootstrap now supports up/down keys as standard.

So if you want <kbd>Tab</kbd> to activate the dropdown, just [get the key code](http://keycode.info) (9) and do the following:

```
$('.input-group input').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 9){ // tab
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-toggle').click();
        $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu a:first').focus();
    }
});
```

And if you want to add further functionality for when the user is focused on a dropdown menu item:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.which){
        case 36: // home
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').find('a:first').focus();
            break;
        case 35: // end
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').find('a:last').focus();
            break;
    }
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpunbb8h/2/) for a demo.

Comment: home/end and letter navigation is missing :-)

Comment: @xamiro-dev See updated answer. You can add letter navigation by [finding the keycode](http://keycode.info) and adding a switch case.

Answer (score -2):

Nice example.

But, Why did you set a `setTimeout`?
Some specific reason?

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".search-option:first").focus();
},100);
```

I made the same example, simulating an input select box, without a timeout. [Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/MGwVM/37/).

Comment: It's likely it was a quirk of the browser at the time.

Comment: @Emzor The code has now been updated if you're interested.

Comment: @rybo111 Thanks a lot for the info :-)